# Take a screenshot in ARKit

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit

I'm currently making my first ARKit app using Xamarin.

I'm trying to take a capture of the AR view (camera view + 3D scene) for the user to save and share.

As suggested in other posts, I'm using [this 'Snapshot' method](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/SceneKit.SCNView.Snapshot()/) on my ARSCNView (named SceneView) to get a UIImage and displaying it with a previously created UIImageView, and have been getting this MemberAccessException : [MemberAccessException screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95rEG.png)

The added stacktrace isn't helping : 
[Stacktrace screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TZox.png)

It seems like Snapshot is internally trying to create an instance of SCNSceneRenderer, hence the error.

I'm a bit desperate there, you would think taking a picture with your 3D scene in an AR view would be simple and natural..

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I still believe this a Xamarin bug, and have found a workaround.

I'm referencing UIViews to be hidden from the screenshot in a List ScreenshotHiddable and i'm using the classic UIView.Capture method on my SceneView :

```
ScreenshotHiddable.HiddenAll(true);
UIImage screenshot = SceneView.Capture();
ScreenshotHiddable.HiddenAll(false);
```

I'll admit this is a bit ugly, but it's working.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you are trying to call `snapshot` on the class itself, rather than an instance of that class. Change your call to call `snapshot` on the view object.

Comment: In this case, SceneView is my ARSCNView. And ARSCNViews inherits from SCNView. So i'm calling it on an instance of the view object.